# Angular 2 configure dragula

Tags: configuration, angular

I have an angular 2 CLI project to which I would like to add the Dragula 3rd party component. I installed the npm module and configured the `angular-cli-build.js` to pick up the component and place it in the `/dist` folder like so:

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
  'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
  'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'ng2-dragula/**/*.+(js|js.map|d.ts)'
]
```

This works, and the files get copied when building.
I reference the module in the import like so:

```
import {Dragula,DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';
```

This also seems to be correct, since visual studio code seems to find the reference.

I guess the problem is with the system-config.ts. Here I add a mapping:

```
const map: any = {
  'ng2-dragula': 'vendor/ng2-dragula'
};
```

But when I start, I get a 404 error showing:

> zone.js:101 GET `http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula`
>   404 (Not Found)

I have tried to add the defaultExtension in 'packages', but that would only append an additional 'ng2-dragula.js' at the end of the link.

The content of the location '.../vendor/ng2-dragula/' is:

- ng2-dragula.js
- ng2-dragula.d.ts

What am I missing? Should this path not pick up the type definition file?

thanks for any help

Joachim

Answer (score 0):

Have you added dragula paths?

```
    paths: {
        'dragula': 'node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.js',
        'ng2-dragula/*': 'node_modules/ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula.js',
```

See if this helps.

Comment: i have tried this, but same result. Actually the documentation for system.js states:
"It is usually advisable to use map configuration over paths unless you need strict control over normalized module names."
So it seems: one or the other....

Comment: Verify couple of things-
1. Are you using both dependencies in package.json - "dragula": "^3.7.0", "ng2-dragula": "^1.1.9",
2. In your component - directives: [Dragula], viewProviders: [DragulaService],